# How to record aux-in audio using Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, getusermedia

In an Electron application that I'm working on, I'm trying to record the audio that I get through my auxillary input (3.5mm jack) in my computer. I don't want to pick up any audio through the built-in microphone.

I was running the following code in order to record five seconds of audio. It works fine, but instead of recording the aux-in, it records the sound from the microphone.

```
const fs = require("fs");

function fiveSecondAudioRecorder() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.start();
      const chunks = [];
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
        chunks.push(event.data);
      });
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/ogg" });
        blob.arrayBuffer().then(arrayBuffer => {
          const buffer = new Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
          fs.writeFile("recorded-audio.ogg", buffer, error => {
            if (error) {
              console.error("Failed to save recorded audio to disk", error);
            } else {
              console.log("Recorded audio was saved to disk");
            }
          });
        });
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      }, 5000);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Failed to access microphone", error);
    });
}

fiveSecondAudioRecorder()
```

I plugged in a 3.5mm jack with an active audio source and expected this to automatically switch the audio input. However, this is not the case and I only manage to pick up the sounds from my microphone. Hence my question: How can I specifically record my aux-in?

Thanks a lot for your help.